# How to make a div appear all over the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a 50% opacity `<div>` appear all over the site, I gave it position absolute and width, height of 100%. but its still appears only parts of the site, if you scroll down, it doesn't cover the rest of the site.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; top:0; left:0; background:#000; position: absolute;">
   loading..
</div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: Code sample would help a lot here...

Comment: <div style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; top:0; left:0; background:#000; position: absolute;"> loading.. </div>

this is the div.. im trigering it after a 'submit'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0em;
            left: 0em; top: 0em; background: black;
            position: fixed;">Loading ...</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This works too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #big {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="big"></id>
    </body>
</html>
```

Setting `top` and `bottom` should do the trick (it also works with `position: fixed`).

Comment: @Boldewyn: Thanks - I've tried it in the latest versions of Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE. I've not tried earlier versions though. @Christopher Altman: They are a little counter-intuitive at first glance, but usually work well.

Answer (score 1):

Use **z-index**, example:

```html
<style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">
 
 .imgWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%x;
 }
 
 .imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  z-index: 100;
 }
 
 .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 }
</style>

<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="imgWrap">
    <p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Text</strong></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="imgDescription">
    <ul style="text-align: left;">
    <li>Description...</li>       
    </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```